# Jasper reposts can't compile an expression that contains JRBeanCollectionDataSource, why?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am creating a report that has a subreport with ireport. The data source for both is java beans. The problem is that when I create the data source expression for the subreport, I will use:

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{actions})
```

which is found on many docs.

When I compile I get:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource cannot be resolved to a type
```

I don't get it, it's a JasperReports class... how can it be missing. I even controlled the 
settings and the Jar with the class is in the classpath.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What type have this field (`actions`)? What happened if you are compiling reports (master and subreport) with help of iReport?

Answer (score 3):

Use data source as in jrxml.

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{actions})]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]here i have a similar situation, for the subreports at main report, that kind of conection works fine, but when i use the same "Data Source Expression" for the subreport of any subreport, i got that error:

JRBeanCollectionDataSource cannot be resolved to a type                 value = (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource)(new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(((java.util.List)field_graficoXY.getValue()))); //$JR_EXPR_ID=135$

You haven't got any solution yet?

main 
  |----subreport (ok)
  |                      |---subreport (error)
  |
  |----subreport (ok)

Comment: i forgot to post the answer at least for my problem, for some reason when you need a "sub-sub-report" your data source expression must be declared with the full name of class, like new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listBean})